# Error: The method 'data' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'. - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Error:

Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
"$${document["price"]}" ?? "Price",
^
lib/screens/product_page.dart:38:65: Error: The method 'data' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'.
  Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data.data();
  ^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_store/constants.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/image_swipe.dart';

class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? productId;
  ProductPage({this.productId});

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {
  final CollectionReference _productRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder(
          future: _productRef.doc(widget.productId).get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                ),
              );
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              //Firebase document data map
              Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data.data();

              //List of images
              List imageList = documentData["images"];

              return ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                children: [
                  ImageSwipe(imageList: imageList,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 24.0,
                      left: 24.0,
                      right: 24.0,
                      bottom: 4.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "\$${documentData["name"]}",
                      style: Constants.boldHeading,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 4.0,
                      horizontal: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "\$${documentData["price"]}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 8.0,
                      horizontal: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "\$${documentData["desc"]}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 24.0,
                      horizontal: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Selected Size",
                      style: Constants.regularDarkText,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }

            //Loading State
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        CustomActionBar(
          hasBackArrow: true,
          hasTitle: false,
          hasBackground: false,
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your second comparison condition is incomplete instead of second if please use if-else, with this condition.

```
else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData){...}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me but thanks for giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, Flutter's newest null-safety features are warning you against possible null value for the `documentData["desc"]` access.

You can check for it and specify a value if the `documentData` returns null for you:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 8.0,
    horizontal: 24.0,
  ),
  child: Text(
    documentData["desc"] ?? "", // Create Text with empty string if documentData["desc"] is null
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
  ),
)
```

You may also need to do this for the other placesses where you are accessing the map.

Comment: Actually, the android studio is showing error in my this line:

Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data.data();

in the last data before the parentheses, it says that:

The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can't be null. 
And when I try using the hint correction it adds a ! null checker n asks me to create a var data.

Comment: Seems like its a typo from your end. Firebase indeed doesn't have a method named `data()`. It should be  `Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data.documents`

Comment: Can you please check the errors in this one:

https://github.com/Bhaskar2510/Final-Sem

I've tried to resolve them but I was unable to solve them myself.